# How to use nginx proxy_pass subroutes from node app?

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy

I have a node app running on port 8002 with different subroutes like '/login' or '/facebook', i also have nginx (v1.6.0) and the following config:

```
  server {
      listen 80;
      server_name my-ghost-blog.com ;

      client_max_body_size 10M;

      location / {
              proxy_pass http://localhost:2368/;
              proxy_set_header Host $host;
              proxy_buffering off;
      }

      location ~ ^/(sitemap.xml) {
            root /var/www/ghost;
      }

      location ~ ^/(robots.txt) {
        root /var/www/ghost;
      }

      #proxy to a node app running on 8002 port
      location ^~ /auth/ {
          proxy_pass http://localhost:8002/;
      }
  }
```

when i go to '/auth/' it works, but when i try to go to a node app'subroute, 404 appears because nginx dont know how to handle it.

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: Do you have anything running on `http://localhost:2368/`?  To me it looks like you're only sending routes with `/auth` to `http://localhost:8002/` but others to `http://localhost:2368/`

Comment: Yes. Ghost is running on that port. But i dont know how to point that those routes inside '/auth/' must be managed by localhost:8002